# How to send Pandas DataFrame as an attachment in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, email, html-email, email-attachments

I have searched around SO and Google a lot but did not get my answer hence ultimately thought to ask here.

I have a *csv* file, which I'm converting to an *html* frame which works fine and I can send that as an *html* frame via Outlook as an email.

Was looking if we can directly send `df.to_html` as an attachment to the e-mail ?

### Below is the code:

This works fine sending as an e-mail with html frame via Outlook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


df = pd.read_csv('graph.csv', names=['Volume_Path', 'Last Acced', 'Year', 'Month', 'Days', '1-24 hrs', '1 hour', '15 mins', 'future'])
df['Volume_Path'] = df['Volume_Path'].str.replace('\t', '')
df = df.replace(np.nan, '')

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
##############################################################################
msg =  "<u><b> Checklist</b></u><br />"
msg = msg + "<br />"
msg += df.to_html(escape=False)
def mail(msg,recipients,key):
        try:
            s = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.xyz.com')
            msg1 = MIMEText(msg, 'html')
            sender = 'tina@xyz.com'
            msg1['From'] = sender
            msg1['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
            msg1['Cc'] =  'mauj@xyz.com'
            msg1['Subject'] = "Mauj Test"
            s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg1.as_string())
            print(f"Mail Sent to {sender}")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"Mail Failed - {error}")
recipients = ['joe@xyz.com']
key=""
mail(msg,recipients,key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to save the `pandas.DataFrame` as an html file on your drive but rather attach it directly I would use `MIMEBase` and attach it to your message

Here `html_object` is the `df.to_html()` object.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

def mail(body,recipients,key, html_object):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('server.com')
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
    part = MIMEBase('text', "html")
    part.set_payload(html_object)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="tbl.html"')
    msg.attach(part)
    sender = 'me@place.com'
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    msg['Subject'] = "Html Test"
    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    print(f"Mail Sent to {sender}")
```

e.g.

`mail('See attached for html file.',["me@place.com"],key="", html_object=df.to_html())`